# Badblocks and fsck say HDD is clean but Linux marks it as read-only

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart, fsck, bad-blocks

I'm relatively new to Linux so I'm not sure why this is happening.

I have this one drive that Linux always marks it as read-only partition. At first I thought it was just the OS so I did a clean install from OpenMediaVault 2.0 to OMV 3.0 (Debian 7 & 8), I ran both `fsck -f /dev/sdd` and `badblocks` but both of them gave me a clean status and yet it still ends up as read-only.

I have around a month left of warranty but I need to provide a good proof for them to accept it.

I don't know how to read SMART data but here it is:

```
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4M5LAL82H
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 20d3675a8
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Apr 24 12:43:14 2017 EEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Disabled
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Wt Cache Reorder: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        (26280) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 266) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x703d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR-K   200   200   051    -    0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS--K   196   168   021    -    3158
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    469
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   200   200   140    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         -OSR-K   200   200   000    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   090   090   000    -    7381
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    102
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    18
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   199   199   000    -    3042
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   113   103   000    -    34
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----CK   100   253   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   ---R--   200   200   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      6  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Queued Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa0-0xa7  GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xa8-0xb7  GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xbd       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL     VS      93  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (6 sectors)
Device Error Count: 2121 (device log contains only the most recent 24 errors)
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 2121 [8] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7376 hours (307 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 00 c9 b1 00 40 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00c9b100 = 13218048

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 20 00 a8 00 00 00 c9 b1 00 40 08  5d+18:07:52.428  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 a0 00 00 80 41 19 b0 40 08  5d+18:06:52.865  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 98 00 00 80 41 19 98 40 08  5d+18:06:52.865  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 90 00 00 80 41 17 20 40 08  5d+18:06:52.864  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 00 88 00 00 80 41 19 70 40 08  5d+18:06:52.864  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 2120 [7] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7364 hours (306 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 bb 04 fa 08 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0xbb04fa08 = 3137665544

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 00 60 00 00 bb 04 fa 08 40 08  5d+06:20:06.696  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  b0 00 d5 00 01 00 00 00 c2 4f 01 00 08  5d+06:19:38.449  SMART READ LOG
  b0 00 d5 00 01 00 00 00 c2 4f 06 00 08  5d+06:19:38.429  SMART READ LOG
  61 00 08 00 38 00 00 00 00 08 00 40 08  5d+06:19:38.407  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  b0 00 d0 00 01 00 00 00 c2 4f 00 00 08  5d+06:19:38.403  SMART READ DATA

Error 2119 [6] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7364 hours (306 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  10 -- 51 00 00 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 00  Error: IDNF at LBA = 0x74440890 = 1950615696

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  61 00 c8 00 10 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 08  5d+06:19:10.175  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:19:10.175  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08  5d+06:19:10.175  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:19:10.175  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:19:10.175  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 2118 [5] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7364 hours (306 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  10 -- 51 00 00 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 00  Error: IDNF at LBA = 0x74440890 = 1950615696

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  61 00 c8 00 e8 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 08  5d+06:19:03.155  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:19:03.155  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08  5d+06:19:03.155  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:19:03.154  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:19:03.154  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 2117 [4] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7364 hours (306 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  10 -- 51 00 00 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 00  Error: IDNF at LBA = 0x74440890 = 1950615696

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  61 00 c8 00 c8 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 08  5d+06:18:56.131  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:56.131  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08  5d+06:18:56.131  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:56.131  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:56.131  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 2116 [3] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7364 hours (306 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  10 -- 51 00 00 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 00  Error: IDNF at LBA = 0x74440890 = 1950615696

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  61 00 c8 00 a8 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 08  5d+06:18:49.121  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:49.120  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08  5d+06:18:49.120  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:49.120  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:49.120  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 2115 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7364 hours (306 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  10 -- 51 00 00 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 00  Error: IDNF at LBA = 0x74440890 = 1950615696

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  61 00 c8 00 88 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 08  5d+06:18:42.106  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:42.106  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08  5d+06:18:42.106  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:42.105  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:42.105  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 2114 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 7364 hours (306 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  10 -- 51 00 00 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 00  Error: IDNF at LBA = 0x74440890 = 1950615696

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  61 00 c8 00 78 00 00 74 44 08 90 40 08  5d+06:18:35.095  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08  5d+06:18:35.095  CHECK POWER MODE
  ef 00 10 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:35.088  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08  5d+06:18:35.088  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08  5d+06:18:35.087  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7378         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7354         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7330         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7306         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7282         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7258         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7239         -
# 8  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      70%      7222         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1135         -
#10  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1061         -
#11  Extended offline    Aborted by host               70%      1052         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1051         -
#13  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      90%         5         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       258 (0x0102)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    34 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     32/40 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:      2/44 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Vendor specific:
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/60 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           -41/85 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    478 (229)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
 230    2017-04-24 04:46    35  ****************
 231    2017-04-24 04:47    35  ****************
 232    2017-04-24 04:48    35  ****************
 233    2017-04-24 04:49    34  ***************
 ...    ..(152 skipped).    ..  ***************
 386    2017-04-24 07:22    34  ***************
 387    2017-04-24 07:23    35  ****************
 ...    ..( 23 skipped).    ..  ****************
 411    2017-04-24 07:47    35  ****************
 412    2017-04-24 07:48    34  ***************
 ...    ..(  5 skipped).    ..  ***************
 418    2017-04-24 07:54    34  ***************
 419    2017-04-24 07:55    35  ****************
 ...    ..(  9 skipped).    ..  ****************
 429    2017-04-24 08:05    35  ****************
 430    2017-04-24 08:06    34  ***************
 ...    ..( 98 skipped).    ..  ***************
  51    2017-04-24 09:45    34  ***************
  52    2017-04-24 09:46    35  ****************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ****************
  55    2017-04-24 09:49    35  ****************
  56    2017-04-24 09:50    34  ***************
 ...    ..(  6 skipped).    ..  ***************
  63    2017-04-24 09:57    34  ***************
  64    2017-04-24 09:58    35  ****************
 ...    ..( 18 skipped).    ..  ****************
  83    2017-04-24 10:17    35  ****************
  84    2017-04-24 10:18    34  ***************
 ...    ..( 11 skipped).    ..  ***************
  96    2017-04-24 10:30    34  ***************
  97    2017-04-24 10:31    35  ****************
 ...    ..( 15 skipped).    ..  ****************
 113    2017-04-24 10:47    35  ****************
 114    2017-04-24 10:48    34  ***************
 ...    ..( 50 skipped).    ..  ***************
 165    2017-04-24 11:39    34  ***************
 166    2017-04-24 11:40    35  ****************
 167    2017-04-24 11:41    34  ***************
 ...    ..( 53 skipped).    ..  ***************
 221    2017-04-24 12:35    34  ***************
 222    2017-04-24 12:36    35  ****************
 223    2017-04-24 12:37    34  ***************
 224    2017-04-24 12:38    35  ****************
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  ****************
 229    2017-04-24 12:43    35  ****************

SCT Error Recovery Control:
           Read:     70 (7.0 seconds)
          Write:     70 (7.0 seconds)

Device Statistics (GP/SMART Log 0x04) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  2            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  2            8  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2            9  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x8000  4       515583  Vendor specific
```

Edit: I unmounted and ran `fsck` again and this time I got this error, it fixed it but it ends up read-only again in a few days. I am also using ext4.

```
:/$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sdd1
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
WDRED3DATABASE: recovering journal
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (477683699, counted=477683887).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong (121845913, counted=121845915).
Fix<y>? yes
WDRED3DATABASE: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
WDRED3DATABASE: 255845/122101760 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 10694498/488378385 blocks
```

Comment: Did you run the fsck after unmount all filesystems, related to the disk? Did you run fsck on filesystems, not entire disk i.e. /dev/sdd1?

Comment: the disk had one filesystem, i stopped everything related to the disk before i unmounted it, yes i did unmount before running fsck, i ran fsck as "fsck -f /dev/sdd1", not on file system (i can ran fsck on filesystem only? how?)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is something wrong with the drive. I think that more likely the problem is in the way you are mounting the drive. Here is a link to fix the mounting issues from the Ubuntu Forums.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/333287/external-hard-disk-read-only

Comment: i am using the default mode in the web ui to mount the hdd, im not using terminal to mount it, same as all the other drives and yet only this one gives me this issue, do you think the problem lies with the ext4 file system? should i try ext3 or btrfs? would it matter if all my other drives are using ext4 and one of them has a different filesystem?

Comment: The file system can matter. What file system is on the drive and what data is on there. Is it storage or an OS

Comment: it is using ext4, its a storage hdd, OS is on an ssd, i tried a full format and the drive stopped getting recognized now..i RMA'd it and will see what happens.